# What is the cost of distributing through Google Stadia?

Tags: business-model

Stadia's business aspects are really scarce to find.

What will the revenue models look like?
Traditional video game model (royalties) or app store model (%)?

Comment: All we can tell you is what Google has published. If it's not published, it's protected by NDA. If it is published, reproducing it here creates an opportunity for the information to diverge if Google updates its terms, leaving inaccurate info here to mislead future readers. Your best bet would be to contact Google's game developer representatives to get the information "straight from the horse's mouth" ;)